# Full Text search using oracle regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, full-text-search

I am trying to use regexp_like() in oracle 11g to achieve text search.

for example I have a table called posts where in title column if I have values

```
'How to create a new post with pictures and videos'
'How to create a new post enter code here'
```

and if I write a query

```
select * from posts where regexp_like(title, '.*pictures.*|.*how.*|.*post.*', 'i')
```

It returns records having both titles where the second value does not have word pictures in it. I know its because I user '|' in the expression.

What I want to achieve is It should return records **only if all the words are present in the column in any order.** Help me with the regex please

Comment: You're trying to do it with a single `regexp_like`, rather than one per search word?

Comment: Yes. I want to do it with a single expression.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#BABGAIHJ

Comment: _" I want to do it with a single expression."_ You can't. Unless by generating a regexp containing all words combinations -- or by somehow sorting words both in the regexp and in the column data. Both seems overcomplicated for something that could be solved by joining several clause using `AND`. If you really have hard constraints on this, you should take a look at Oracle text as it was suggested in an other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

I wrote a plunker in AngularJS. It is just to demonstrate how the regular expression works.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6WrCCAfNwidVxKkRFH9l?p=preview

The regular expression you can use is

/^(?=.*(pictures))(?=.*(post))(?=.*(how))[a-zA-Z ]{1,100}$/

This means pictures, post, how should be there in the given paragraph.
You can adjust the length of the paragrah as per your requirement.

```
<form role="form" name="myform">
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user" name="inputfield" required="true"  ng-pattern="/^(?=.*(pictures))(?=.*(post))(?=.*(how))[a-zA-Z ]{1,100}$/">
        <span ng-show="myform.inputfield.$dirty && !myform.inputfield.$error.required && myform.inputfield.$error.pattern">
          <small class="text-danger">
          Not Matching
        </small>
       </span>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That is case-sensitive in your demo, but more importantly - unfortunately - Oracle only [supports a limited subset or regex](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020), mostly POSIX with a few Perl extensions.

Comment: To remove case sensitivity u can use the reg exp as  -->  "/^(?=.*(pictures|PICTURES))(?=.*(post|POST))(?=.*(how|HOW))[a-zA-Z ]{1,100}$"